# i am unable to understand why this code has marked things

Tags: java, boolean

I was trying to understand collection framework using a real life example of a theatre class containing an inner class named seat ..

Since the code was there I started to create my own code but I got stuck at a point and then I referred to the code provided to me. The code is to create a java program that could be used to book seats in a theatre.

```
private boolean reservedSeat=false;

    private Boolean reserve(){
    if(!reservedSeat){
                    reservedSeat=true;
                    System.out.println("Seat "+seatNumber+" is reserved.");
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return false;
    }
```

This code is to reserve seat in theatre. This code was defined in the inner class Seat . I am unable to understand what this if statement mean by 
(!reservedSeat), reservedSeat is already initialised to false then 
!reservedSeat would be equal to true, but the following lines in the if block statement is again setting reservedSeat=true so what actually is happening in this code.
I am getting a thought that this if statement is saying that if reservedSeat is true i.e. seat is reserved,set reservedSeat to true. But I know that is gibberish. Please help me with the underlying concept of what it actually wants to say.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with [tag:collections] or [tag:inner-classes]. It is just about `boolean` and the `!` operator. Unclear what you're really asking.

Comment: That code appears to be a method to reserve a seat, not to check if it is currently reserved. So if it isn't currently reserved, it will reserve it & return `true`

Comment: `!reservedSeat` just means “run the following code if `reservedSeat` is false”. `!reservedSeat` does not change the value of `reservedSeat`, which is why it must be changed on the following line.

Comment: thank you @ChrisGilardi I was under wrong impression for so long .Thank you mate

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a typical construct.

The code checkst if the seat is not yet reserved (`if (!reserved)`)
If that check succeeds the seat gets reserved (`reservedSeat = true`)
and `true` is returned, as a signal to the caller that reserving the seat was successful.

If the first check was not successful, i.e. the seat is already reserved the method just returns `false` signalling that the attempt to reserve that seat failed.

I recommend turning the condition around so one has to deal with one less negation:

```
private boolean reservedSeat=false;

private Boolean reserve() {

    if(reservedSeat) {
        return false;
    } else {

        reservedSeat=true;
        System.out.println("Seat "+seatNumber+" is reserved.");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Also welcome to SO. Consider upvoting the answer if it was helpful and/or accepting it if it solved your problem.